# javascript leave max 3 occurrences of the same obj in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, filter

If I populate an array of pairs (inside a get json) like so:

```
var arrItems = [];
for (let y=0; y<50 ;y++){
    var titl = data.item[y].name;
    var img = data.item[y].image[0].url;
    arrItems.push({t:titl,i:img});
}
```

How can I then filter it to leave only 3 pairs where `value` is the same?

**Example:**

```
arrItems = [
    {t:one,i:square.jpg},
    {t:two,i:square.jpg},
    {t:three,i:square.jpg},
    {t:four,i:square.jpg},
    {t:five,i:triangle.jpg}
];
```

**Becomes**

```
arrItems = [
    {t:one,i:square.jpg},
    {t:two,i:square.jpg},
    {t:three,i:square.jpg},
    {t:five,i:triangle.jpg}
];
```

Both JavaScript or jQuery are OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a hash table and count the occurences of the wanted property and filter with a max value.

```js
var items = [{ t: 'one', i: 'square.jpg' }, { t: 'two', i: 'square.jpg' }, { t: 'three', i: 'square.jpg' }, { t: 'four', i: 'square.jpg' }, { t: 'five', i: 'triangle.jpg' }],
    count = {},
    result = items.filter(({ i }) => {
        count[i] = (count[i] || 0) + 1;
        return count[i] <= 3;
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be some more efficient ways to write it, but I would think the easiest to understand is the straightforward iteration with counting:

```
var counts = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arrItems.length; i++) {
    var item = arrItems[i];
    var count = counts[item.i] || 0;
    if (count >= 3) {
        arrItems.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
    } else {
        counts[item.i] = ++count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function

```
    var arrItems = [
        {t:'one',i:'square.jpg'},
        {t:'two',i:'square.jpg'},
        {t:'three',i:'square.jpg'},
        {t:'four',i:'square.jpg'},
        {t:'five',i:'triangle.jpg'}
    ];

    var output = arrItems.reduce((acc, {t,i})=>{
        acc['mem'][i] = (acc['mem'][i] || 0) + 1;
        acc['mem'][i] <= 3 ? acc['output'].push({t, i}) : ''; 
        return acc;
    }, {'mem':{}, 'output':[]});

console.log(output);
```